A LINK error occurred when compiling QGIS3.34.8 or qgis_core of 3.38.0 in Windows using VS2019
I got a LINK error when compiling qgis_core in QGIS using VS2019 Release x64 for Windows, and it looked like this:
4>draco.lib(point_cloud.cc.obj) : error LNK2019:   Unparsable external symbol __std_find_trivial_4,  function "int * __cdecl std::_Find_unchecked<int *,int>(int *,int * const,int const &)" (??  The symbol is quoted in $_Find_unchecked@PEAHH @st@@YAPEAHPEAHQEAHAEBH@Z)

4>absl_log_internal_log_sink_set.lib(log_sink_set.cc.obj) : error LNK2019:   External symbol __std_find_trivial_8 that cannot be resolved,  Function "class absl::lts_20240116::LogSink * * __cdecl std::_Find_unchecked<class absl::lts_20240116::LogSink * *,class  absl::lts_20240116::LogSink *>(class absl::lts_20240116::LogSink * *,class absl::lts_20240116::LogSink * * const,class   absl::lts_20240116::LogSink * const &)" (??  $_Find_unchecked@PEAPEAVLogSink@lts_20240116@absl@@PEAV123@@std@@YAPEAPEAVLogSink@lts_20240116@absl@@PEAPEAV123@QEAPEAV1  It is quoted in 23@AEBQEAV123@@Z)

4>absl_str_format_internal.lib(arg.cc.obj) : error LNK2019:   Unresolvable external symbol __std_find_trivial_1,  The function "char const * __cdecl std::_Find_unchecked<char const *,char>(char const *,char const *,char const &)" (??  The symbol is quoted in $_Find_unchecked@PEBDD @st@@YAPEBDPEBDQEBDAEBD@Z)

4>absl_strings.lib(charconv_bigint.cc.obj) : error LNK2001: cannot parse the external symbol __std_find_trivial_1

4>absl_str_format_internal.lib(arg.cc.obj) : error LNK2019:  unparsed external symbol __std_find_trivial_2, function "private:  static bool __cdecl absl::lts_20240116::str_format_internal::FormatArgImpl::Dispatch<wchar_t const *>(union   absl::lts_20240116::str_format_internal::FormatArgImpl::Data,class   absl::lts_20240116::str_format_internal::FormatConversionSpecImpl,void *)" (??  $Dispatch@PEB_W@FormatArgImpl@str_format_internal@lts_20240116@absl@@CA_NTData@0123@VFormatConversionSpecImpl@123@PEAX@Z  The symbol is referenced in

I asked ChatGPT, but the answer it gave was to check if the library was in the project and regenerate or check the Settings, but in fact I checked and changed all of these and it was still wrong.
How can I fix this?

This comment will be rightfully deleted, but I can't help myself. How can we mere mortals compete with ChatGP? You have no other option but wait for ChatGP V3247.
